# Yii Postgress Json queries for operator with question marks ?, ?|, ?&

Tags: php, postgresql, yii, conditional-statements, jsonb

How to write SQL queries to [support JSON](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html) where conditions matching for operators ? , ?|, ?&.

```
id : 12,
name: 'Harry Pottor',
type: ['Fiction', 'Horror', 'Adventure' ]
```

In Yii, when I write query for JSON array check with `?&` operator gives me error. This query run successfully in pgAdmin

```
SELECT id, name 
FROM books 
WHERE 
type ?& array['Fiction', 'Horror']

$commandSql = $connection->createCommand($sql);
```

But `?` mark operator gets replaced with $1 i.e. going for bind value.

How to do this type of queries in Yii?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I face same problem

```
SELECT * FROM company WHERE jsonb_exists_all(technology::jsonb, array['ERP']);
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM company WHERE jsonb_exists_all(technology, array['ERP']);
```

refer this link 
http://www.scriptscoop2.com/t/984beb7bce86/postgresql-json-select-query-replacement-in-php-yii2.html